# Raspberry PI 3 and MOSFET IRF520 driver module to control DC Fan speed

Tags: pi-3, modules

I have been trying to connect a 5v dc fan with MOSFET IRF520 module and rp3. When I give 5v of rp3 to the SIG of module and connect the module with an external 9V battery, the fan works.
But, when I connect SIG with 3.3V, the fan stops.
At first, I thought that maybe it's because the gate of module needs more threshold to allow current to flow through but when i connected an LED with a 1k ohm resister and gave 3.3v from rp3 to SIG, the LED lit up signifying that gate is opened for 3.3v
I am so confused why my fan is not working as I have to connect it to a separate GPIO to control its speed.
Please help.
Also I can't really understand the purpose of VCC on the module. I have tried playing with it but nothing works.

Comment: It is far from clear what you have connected.

Comment: `gate is opened` ... what does that mean? ... conducting or not conducting

Comment: What module?  What fan? Please edit info into question.

Comment: Why would you want to use a 100 V 9.7 A MOSFET to control a 5V fan? This is unlikely to work.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you seem to have no idea how to phrase a question. All I know for certain is that you are using the wrong part (IRF520) for any application involving a fan for the Raspberry Pi.